# DAX for populating column value based on previous row of same column

Tags: for-loop, recursion, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I am trying to replicate this Excel formula or for loop that calculates the current row value based on the previous row value of the same column.
When value = 1, Result = Rank * 1
Else, Result = Rank * previous Result

```
| Value | Rank | Result |
| ----- | ---- | ------ |
|   1   |   3  |   3    |
|   2   |   2  |   6    |
|   3   |   1  |   6    |
```

I already tried generating a series table to get the Value and Rank columns but I am unable to refer to the existing Result column to update the same. Is there a way to get this done using DAX for dynamic number of rows?

Comment: DAX can't handle recursive calculations... The only realistic option here is to pre- calculate this field at the source and then import it.

Comment: @RADO, any suggestions for replicating this on SQL server then? like a stored proc?

Comment: Yes, you can use a stored procedure and write the recursion in SQL. I'd recommend to post it as a separate question with the appropriate tags.

Comment: @RADO that's true - it cannot handle recursion, but it's powerful enough to solve this problem - look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but you need to get your mindset out of recursion. Notice that I did `[Rank]` even for `[Value]` equal 1, as `[Rank] * [Value]` in that case is equal `[Rank]` (value equals 1, right?).

```
Result =
IF (
    Table[Value] = 1,
    [Rank],
    [Rank] *
    PRODUCTX (
        FILTER ( Table, Table[Value] < EARLIER ( Table[Value] ) ),
        [Rank]
    )
)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

The previous one was unneccessarily complex:

```
Result =
CALCULATE (
    PRODUCT ( [Rank] ),
    FILTER ( Table, [Value] <= EARLIER ( [Value] ) )
)
```

Comment: that does help actually! I was playing around with SUMX,MINX along with EARLIER but completely missed PRODUCTX which does the trick - so thank you!